# How do I retrieve a JavaScript array in a server side button click handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have the following jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnGetIDs').click(function getIDs() {
            var checkedIds = $(":checkbox:checked").map(function () {
                return this.id;
            }).get();
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is used for the creation of the checkboxes (it is nested within a lengthy foreach datarow in datatable).

```
                    results.Append("<td> <input id=" + RosteredCareID + " type=\"checkbox\" unchecked>        </td>");
```

Which I can see, from debugging in the browser, is working as intended and creating an array of IDs.

The intended functionality is:
1. System loads page
2. User clicks some check boxes
3. User clicks submit
4. System gets the IDs of checked boxes and stores in array

Here

```
    protected void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] IDs = new string[20];

        // IDs = "";


    }
```

So how I can access the jQuery array from the btnConfirm_Click event?

I have tried a scriptmanager line of code but it was causing errors with a scriptmanager on a masterpage.

Comment: You mentioned an error and something you tried. But you didn't show *what* you tried or *what* the error was. You shouldn't leave us guessing. You also need to show the markup for your checkboxes in order to have a *complete* question. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You're mixing up server-side and client-side events.

Comment: Why is jQuery/Javascript needed *at all* for this problem? Are you submitting via Ajax?

Comment: You don't need this kind of manual logic to gather checked checkboxes. Use `form.serializeArray()` - https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a name property to your checkbox markup.

```
results.Append("<td><input id='" + RosteredCareID + "' type='checkbox' name='" + RosteredCareID  + "' unchecked /></td>");
```

(Notice I properly quoted your ID. And I used single quotes within the JS string to avoid the need to escape your double quotes.)

Then in the server side, the values will be available in the `Request.Form` property. You can enumerate over them like this:

```
foreach (var name in Request.Form.AllKeys)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Form Name: " + name + " Form Value: " + Request.Form[key]);
}
```

If the value is checked, it will be in there.

There may be lots of form values, so you'll need to filter them to get only what you want. I suggest you prefix your name with a particular string. Ex:

```
results.Append("<td><input id='" + RosteredCareID + "' type='checkbox' name='RosterCareCB_" + RosteredCareID  + "' unchecked /></td>");
```

Then on the server side, filter on that prefix.

```
var checkedIds = new List<string>();
foreach (var name in Request.Form.AllKeys)
{
    if(name.StartsWith("RosterCareCB_") && Request.Form[name] == "on")
    {
        checkedIds.Add(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can see when I breakline on the foreach that my RosteredCareIDs are held within the Request.Form.AllKeys. There is also a viewstate and some controls from the page. How I can I pull out just my IDs? Also thank you for the tip on single quotes!

Comment: It says that key does not exist when I try and run it

Comment: @JoshCooper Then the key does not exist. Like I said, they'll only show up in there if they're checked. If I were you, I'd name my ID's with a certain naming format so you know which form values to pull. Then check to see if they're in there. If they're in there, then double check the posted value to make 100% sure it's checked. Then you'll know what was checked and you can do further processing.

Comment: When I response.write the contents of the request I get __EVENTTARGET
__EVENTARGUMENT
__VIEWSTATE
78
91
92
93
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder2$ddlReason
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder2$btnConfirm
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder2$hdnCheckedIds
.
only 4-7 are IDs how can i get just those?

Comment: @JoshCooper That's why I said use a certain naming format. For example, if the name always starts with "RosterCareCB" then filter the retrieved values where the name starts with "RosterCareCB"